# Why do so many standard C functions tamper with parameters instead of returning values?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, std, free

Many functions like strcat, strcpy and alike don't return the actual value but change one of the parameters (usually a buffer). This of course creates a boatload of side effects.
Wouldn't it be far more elegant to just return a new string? Why isn't this done?

Example:

```
char *copy_string(char *text, size_t length) {

    char *result = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        result[i] = text[i];
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    char *copy = copy_string("Hello World", 12);
    // *result now lingers in memory and can not be freed?
}
```

I can only guess it has something to do with memory leaking since there is dynamic memory being allocated inside of the function which you can not free internally (since you need to return a pointer to it).

**Edit**: From the answers it seems that it is good practice in C to work with parameters rather than creating new variables. So I should aim for building my functions like that?

**Edit 2**: Will my example code lead to a memory leak? Or can *result be free'd?

Comment: With standard function you can fail to declare buffer dimensions, and the same with your function where width is passed by parameters. So where is the improvement? Moreover **your call to function is bugged: `11` does not take care of null terminator** , so... BTW _more elegant_ is fuzzy..

Comment: Your solution is more or less fine, but it's very expensive, because `malloc` may take longtime.

Comment: It's pretty easy to write functions that behave like you want on top of the C library. The reverse would be more or less impossible.

Comment: "it seems that it is good practice in C to work with parameters rather than creating new variables. So I should aim for building my functions like that?" Yes. You should also document your function with comments, telling the caller that they need to pass pointers to allocated buffers. Similarly, you can leave error handling to the caller, if you document that your function does not perform it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your original question:  C, at the time it was designed, was tailored to be a language of maximum efficiency.  It was, basically, just a nicer way of writing assembly code (the guy who designed it, wrote his own compiler for it).

What you say (that parameters are often used rather than return codes) is mainly true for string handling.  Most other functions (those that deal with numbers for example) work through return codes as expected. Or they only modify values for parameters if they have to return more than one value.

String handling in C today is considered one of the major (if not THE major) weakness in C.  But those functions were written with performance in mind, and with the machines available those days (and the intent of performance) working on the callers buffers was the way of choice.

Re your edit 1: Today other intents may apply.  Performance usually isn't the limiting factor.  Equally or important are readability, robustness, pronenees to error.  And generally, as said, the string handling in C is today generally considered an horrible relic of the past.  So it's basically your choice, depending on your intent.

Re your edit 2: Yes, the memory will leak.  You need to call *free(copy);*  Which ties into edit 1: proneness of error - it's easy to forget the free and create leaks that way (or attempt to free it twice or access it after it was freed).  It may be more readable and more more prone to error too (even more than the clunky original C approach of modifying the caller's buffer).

Generally, I'd suggest, whenever you have the choice, to work with a newer dialect that support std-string or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do so many standard C functions tamper with parameters instead of returning values?

Because that's often what the users of the C library wants.

> Many functions like strcat, strcpy and alike don't return the actual value but change one of the parameters (usually a buffer). This of course creates a boatload of side effects. Wouldn't it be far more elegant to just return a new string? Why isn't this done?

It's not very efficient to allocate a memory and it'll require the user to free() them later, which is an unnecessary burden on the user. Efficiency and letting users do what they want (even if they want shoot themselves in the foot) is a part of C's philosophy.
Besides, there are syntax/implementation issues. For example, how can the following be done if the strcpy() function actually returns a newly allocated string?

```
char arr[256] = "Hello";
strcpy(arr, "world");
```

Because C doesn't allow you assign something to an array (`arr`).

Basically, you are questioning C is the way it is. For that question, the common answer is "historical reasons".

Comment: Wouldn't be strcat more appropriate for your example code?

Comment: strcat() can also be an example. But the general gist is the same. C tries to be fast and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

- Properly designed functions should only concern themselves with their designated purpose, and not unrelated things such as memory allocation.
- Making a hard copy of the string would make the function far slower.

So for your example, if there is a need for a hard copy, the caller should `malloc` the buffer and afterwards call `strcpy`. That separates memory allocation from the algorithm.

On top of that, good design practice dictates that the module that allocated memory should also be responsible for freeing it. Otherwise the caller might not even realize that the function is allocating memory, and there would be a memory leak. If the caller instead is responsible for the allocation, then it is obvious that the caller is also responsible for clean-up.

---

Overall, C standard library functions are designed to be as fast as possible, meaning they will strive to meet the case where the caller has minimal requirements. A typical example of such a function is `malloc`, which doesn't even set the allocated data to zero, because that would take extra time. Instead they added an additional function `calloc` for that purpose.

Other languages have different philosophies, where they would for example force a hard copy for all string handling functions ("immutable objects"). This makes the function easier to work with and perhaps also the code easier to read, but it comes at the expense of a slower program, which needs more memory.

This is one of the main reasons why C is still widely used for development. It tends is much faster and more efficient than any other language (except raw assembler).

Comment: Will there be a memory leak with my example? Or can *result be freed?

Comment: @AdHominem It depends on how the program is written. Nothing prevents the caller from freeing it, although that would be bad program design. Proper design would have a clean-up function located in the same module as `copy_string`, which the caller calls when the data is not needed any longer.